# Checking that user dotfiles are not group or world writeable

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I need to check whether user dot-files are not group or world writeable:
The below command will list all the files:

```
find /home/ -name "\.*" -perm /g+w,o+w
```

Output:

```
/home/system/.java
/home/ldap/.java
```

My query is, how do I SSH to the machine (multiple VM's) and then find these files using the above command and correct it using:

```
chmod go-w /home/<\USER><\FILE>
chmod go-w /home/<\USER>/<\DIRECTORY>
```

I need to write a shell script.

Comment: Is the question about how to execute the command remotely, how to find the files, or how to change mode for the list of files at a certain location?

Comment: yes, its related to executing the command remotely and correcting the misconfigured files (see output above) found by the above find command

Comment: just append `-exec chmod g-w,o-w "{}" \;` to the end of your find.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use for loop to run chmod on all files/folder returned by find command.

```
for i in `find /home/ -name ".*" -perm /g+w,o+w`; do chmod go-w $i; done
```

This will run chmod go-w on all files/folder which were found with the find command.

This is how it would look like a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find /home/ -name ".*" -perm /g+w,o+w`; do chmod go-w $i; done
```

---

EDIT:

Appending just `-exec chmod g-w,o-w "{}" \;` to the end of find, as suggested by Drav Sloan in comment of question is lot more efficient then for loop.

So you can just use

```
find /home/ -name ".*" -perm /g+w,o+w -exec chmod g-w,o-w "{}" \;
```

or as bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/ -name ".*" -perm /g+w,o+w -exec chmod g-w,o-w "{}" \;
```

---

If you save it as script.sh, you can run it with:

```
bash script.sh
```

If you want to run for loop remotely, something like this should work if you place script.sh on all machines:

```
ssh machine "bash script.sh"
```

or if it is only locally

```
ssh machine 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

If you want to run a script on multiple servers, you can either put ssh in for loop, or use pssh utility.

If you put all your servers in serverlist file, you can use pssh to run the local script on all those servers:

```
pssh -h serverlist -i -I < script.sh
```

or with for loop and ssh:

```
for i in `cat serverslist`; do ssh $i 'bash -s' < script.sh; done
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is force the files be non-writable, whouldn't following be sufficient?

```
$ chmod g-w,o-w ~/.*
```